# ignore "/use_sim_time" parameter

Tags: ros, use-sim-time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is there a way to ignore the "/use_sim_time" parameter in a node, so that it uses the system time instead of clock?
Thanks!

cheers
Jonas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32468/ignore-%22/use_sim_time%22-parameter/) by [robotrover](https://answers.ros.org/users/1387/robotrover/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use [`ros::WallTime` and `ros::WallDuration`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Time#Wall_Time) in your node.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotrover](https://answers.ros.org/users/1387/robotrover/) on 2012-04-24**:
Thanks for the hint! I wanted to use a ros::Timer, and your answer pointed me to the createWallTimer method. Jonas

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-24**:
@robotrover Please accept this answer using the checkmark at left so others know it's answered without reading the whole thread.